# Camel Spring Boot Prometheus - Disable direct component metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to expose `/management/prometheus` endpoint from a Camel Spring Boot application. While doing so, I observed all the requests that I trigger to the rest endpoint are getting pushed to the prometheus endpoint.
E.g. PFB. The requests triggered from Postman are visible in the prometheus endpoint.
[image]

Here's the request that I triggered to my endpoint
[image: Request]

Is there a way I can get rid of these requests getting into the prometheus endpoint. My concern for a bigger JSON, if it keeps on pushing the requests to prometheus endpoint, heap will keep on growing and I might encounter an OOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Posting for anyone who could be going through the same. Just had to exclude the `ObservationAutoConfiguration.class` from the Main class. Post this I saw the requests were not getting pushed to prometheus endpoint.