camel-observation-starter creates metrics with full request data
I have a Spring Boot 3 project with Camel. I am using org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-observation-starter for tracing.
I have setup the project using autoconfig instructions and this blog from the camel-observation team.
My tracing is working, and metrics are being produced (using prometheus). My problem is that the default metrics produced by camel-observation-starter are crazy, every request and response is stored as its own metric, so essentially every request/response is stored in full on the prometheus endpoint.

I would like to use camel-observation-starter for tracing, but stop it producing any metrics. I cannot find a way to do this. Any suggestions?
Some versions of my components:
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies 2023.0.0
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent 3.2.2
org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-dependencies 4.4.1
org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-observation-starter
io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus

What version of Camel do you use? And can you share some more details about those long metric names, where do you think this comes from, do you really have very long camel endpoint uris, or what is it ?

Hi @ClausIbsen. I have updated my question with some versions. The metric id being produced seems to be the name of the response class, with the actual response object fields in some kind of key-value format.

I also spotted someone with the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78043322/camel-spring-boot-prometheus-disable-direct-component-metrics

I'm posting a second answer as I found a much better way to filter out these metrics based on a tag.
@Bean
public MeterFilter meterFilter() {
    return new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public MeterFilterReply accept(final Meter.Id id) {
            if ("camel-direct".equals(id.getTag("component"))) {
                return MeterFilterReply.DENY;
            }
            return MeterFilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }
    };
}


I was able to fix this, at least in a fairly unsatisfactory way. I created a MeterFilter to remove metrics with excessively long names. This left my tracing in tact, as well as the prometheus metrics I want, such as the default spring actuator metrics and my custom metrics.
@Bean
public MeterFilter meterFilter() {
    return new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public MeterFilterReply accept(final Meter.Id id) {
            if (id.getName().length() > 100) {
                return MeterFilterReply.DENY;
            }
            return MeterFilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }
    };
}

